# cmp and echo line that is different

Tags: bash

So I have two text files. I do a `cmp`:

```
karl@karl-laptop ~ $ cmp package1.json package2.json 
package1.json package2.json differ: char 339, line 14
```

These files differ one line. Is there a way to display this line if they are indeed different?

Comment: Use `diff` or `comm` instead of `cmp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `diff` instead of `cmp`:

```
diff package1.json package2.json
```

Answer (score 0):

`cmp` has a -b flag that should do what you need.

`cmp -b package1.json package2.json`